# What does "be subscribed to a channel" mean for Twilio Programmable Chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Looking for a help to understand what "be subscribed to a channel" actually means for Twilio chat. Didn't find any definition of that in the documentation.

According to the docs there are 2 methods to fetch available channels for a specific user:

1. [getSubscribedChannels](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.2/docs/Client.html#getSubscribedChannels__anchor). Description says `Get the current list of all subscribed Channels`
2. [getUserChannelDescriptors](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.2/docs/Client.html#getUserChannelDescriptors__anchor). Description says `Get the User's (created by, joined or invited to) channels directory content`

With second it's pretty much clear what it does, but the first one confuses me a bit. After some research I read that "subscribed" means listening to channel's events, i.e `messageAdded`. But this method also returns channels where current user is just a member and no listeners are set up.

Would appreciate if someone could bring more clarity to this `subscribed` topic and expected results from `getSubscribedChannels()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Subscribed channels are channels that the user is a member of](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/channels#get-a-list-of-subscribed-channels). A user becomes a member of a channel when they [join](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.2/docs/Channel.html#join__anchor) the channel. So getSubscribedChannels gets the list of channels where the user has joined as a member. This does not include channels that they use has been invited to and hasn't joined, or channels the user created and left.